# Joining two tables in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables. One of the tables have 7 values and the other table has 5 values. These tables have their primary keys in common. I want to join both tables this way:
If I have a Table

```
English              French
-------------------- --------------------
one                  Un
two                  Deux
three                Trois
four                 Quatre
four                 Quattro
five                 Cinq
five                 Cinco
```

And another one:

```
English              French
-------------------- --------------------
one                  aaaaa
two                  bbbbb
three                ccccc
four                 
five
```

I want to have a table like this:

```
English              French
-------------------- --------------------
one                  Un
one                  aaaaa
two                  Deux
two                  bbbb
three                Trois
three                ccccc
four                 Quatre
four                 Quattro
four                 --------
five                 Cinq
five                 Cinco
five                 ----------
```

I tried using join but it does a linear combination of the values `four` and `five`. How can I go about doing this? Thanks.

**Edit**: SQL query:

```
SELECT l.date_location, l.duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru 
FROM  locations l, restitutions r
UNION
SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru
FROM  locations l, restitutions r


id_agence num_immatriculation num_client km_restitution km_parcouru state date_restitution 
1   406BON69    1002    30000   1000    BON 29-MAY-10
3   785CIM13    1001    56580   80  BON 09-AUG-08
5   800BBB75    1000    2020    20  BON 24-APR-11
4   307VXN78    1000    20040   40  BON 28-JAN-11
2   290UTT92    1004    30030   30  BON 01-AUG-10
5   777SET13    1005    4030    30  BON 26-APR-11
2   179CLV92    1004    15015   15  BON 03-FEB-11
5   400AAA75    1003    1020    20  BON 18-SEP-11
5   666NEF69    1004    3040    40  BON 15-APR-11
2   111AAA75    1001    20020   20  BON 21-DEC-09
1   333CCC78    1001    43250   40  BON 27-DEC-09
2   260CDE95    1003    79000   430 BON 10-SEP-09
4   307VXN78    1003    20090   90  BON 11-FEB-11
1   123ABC78    1003    10010   10  BON 04-OCT-10
1   222BBB77    1001    9050    50  BON 23-DEC-09


Locations
    id_agence num_immatricul  num_client duree   date_location
    2   406BON69    1002    20  10-MAY-10
    3   785CIM13    1001    3   07-AUG-08
    5   800BBB75    1000    7   18-APR-11
    4   307VXN78    1000    5   24-JAN-11
    1   290UTT92    1004    1   31-JUL-10
    5   777SET13    1005    4   23-APR-11
    1   179CLV92    1004    5   30-JAN-11
    5   400AAA75    1003    2   17-SEP-11
    2   123ABC78    1003    4   01-OCT-10
    5   666NEF69    1004    5   11-APR-11
    1   111AAA75    1001    2   20-DEC-09
    1   222BBB77    1001    2   22-DEC-09
    1   333CCC78    1001    3   25-DEC-09
    1   260CDE95    1003    10  01-SEP-09
    4   307VXN78    1003    13  30-JAN-11
    2   123ABC78    1003    8   20-NOV-11
    2   406BON69    1002    10  20-NOV-11
```

Desired Result

```
id_agence num_immatricul  num_client duree   date_location date_restitution
2   406BON69    1002    20  10-MAY-10     date_restitution
3   785CIM13    1001    3   07-AUG-08     date_restitution
5   800BBB75    1000    7   18-APR-11     date_restitution
4   307VXN78    1000    5   24-JAN-11     date_restitution
1   290UTT92    1004    1   31-JUL-10     date_restitution
5   777SET13    1005    4   23-APR-11     date_restitution
1   179CLV92    1004    5   30-JAN-11     date_restitution
5   400AAA75    1003    2   17-SEP-11     date_restitution
2   123ABC78    1003    4   01-OCT-10     date_restitution
5   666NEF69    1004    5   11-APR-11     date_restitution
1   111AAA75    1001    2   20-DEC-09      date_restitution
1   222BBB77    1001    2   22-DEC-09     date_restitution
1   333CCC78    1001    3   25-DEC-09     date_restitution
1   260CDE95    1003    10  01-SEP-09     date_restitution
4   307VXN78    1003    13  30-JAN-11     date_restitution
2   123ABC78    1003    8   20-NOV-11      ----------------
2   406BON69    1002    10  20-NOV-11      ---------------
```

Apart from the column name, where i put date_restitution contains real dates.

Comment: imho, `union all ` will help you

Comment: @mkab, can you include the structures of both tables? Also, are you sure you want a cartesian join between locations and restitutions?

Comment: ok let me add it. It'll take some time though

Comment: @MarkBannister: I've added both tables

Comment: @mkab: Why not post your desired results in your question?

Comment: @MarkBannister: I've posted my desired results

Comment: @mkab: I have posted an updated answer, based on the supplied desired results. This does not resemble the original question in any way.

Comment: @MarkBannister Wow it worked!! Thanks a lot. I'm sorry if the original question doesn't resemble my supplied result. Guessed I was confused myself. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MarkBannister:  Since locations and restitutions have almost the same attributs and data, I finally decided in changing my database and creating a new table that contains both the attributes of location and restitution and setting some not availabe values to null. I did this in order to facilitate some queries I might have to do in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a UNION:

```
select English, French from Table1
UNION ALL
select English, French from Table2
```

or a full outer join

```
select distinct coalesce(T1.English, T2.English), coalesce(T1.French, T2.French)
from Table1 T1
full outer join Table2 T2 on T1.English = T2.English
```

EDIT:

Assuming you want restitutions.date_restitution to appear in place of date_location for restitution records -

```
SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree,  to_number(null) km_restitution, to_number(null) km_parcouru
FROM  locations l
UNION ALL
SELECT r.num_client, r.date_restitution date_location, 0 duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru
FROM  restitutions r
```

FURTHER EDIT (based on supplied results):

```
select l.id_agence,
       l.num_immatricul,
       l.num_client,
       l.duree,
       l.date_location,
       decode(r.date_restitution, NULL,'----------------', 'date_restitution')
           as date_restitution -- or just r.date_restitution
from location l
left outer join restitution r
on l.id_agence = r.id_agence and 
   l.num_immatricul = r.num_immatricul and 
   l.num_client = r.num_client and 
   l.date_location <= r.date_restitution
```

Comment: I have an error using `UNION ALL`: `query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Comment: @mkab: you need the same number (and type) of columns in both unioned queries - the queries here should work, but if you have amended them to match your actual tables then you may have introduced a discrepancy between the structure of the queries. Can you include the actual query you tried to run?

Comment: `SELECT l.date_location, l.duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru 
FROM  locations l, restitutions r
UNION
SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru
FROM  locations l, restitutions r`

Comment: @mkab, Try `SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree, r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru FROM locations l, restitutions r UNION ALL SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree, r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru FROM locations l, restitutions r` .

Comment: it works but I have a lot of duplicates. 510 values from a twao tables that contain 17 values for one and 15 values for the other

Comment: On a union, you can't get more rows in your resultset than you had in your input sets - so if you only had 17 and 15 rows, you would not get more than 32 rows. Have you included all relevant selection conditions in both unioned queries?

Comment: Perhaps I'd have to join the two tables. Location and restitution share a key `num_client`.

Comment: Actually in table location the last two values aren't "restituted" in the table restitution. So I want these two values to be shown in the resulting table but with the column `km_restitution` and `km_parcouru` containing nothing

Comment: I tried your query. It still gives me 32 values with or withouut `UNION ALL`. I'm reasoning about something. Locations contains 17 values and restitution contains 15 values. The last two values of location haven't been "restituted" in the restitution. These values are been used for the second time. So the resulting table should contain 15 values maximum. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: And i don't want restitutions.date_restitution to appear in place of date_location.

Comment: @mkab: No, your reasoning is completely wrong - union adds all the values from one dataset to all values from another dataset, so you would expect 32 rows in the combined dataset. This is what your original question requested - to add 7 rows and 5 rows to produce 12 rows.

Comment: Ok I now understand what union does. location and restitutions have keys id_agence, num_client and num_immatriculation in common. So do i have to join the two tables again on these keys?

Comment: I tried joining them but it doesn't work:  `(SELECT l.num_client, l.date_location, l.duree,  to_number(null) km_restitution, to_number(null) km_parcouru
FROM  locations l

UNION 
SELECT r.num_client, r.date_restitution date_location, 0 duree,  r.km_restitution, r.km_parcouru
FROM  restitutions r)
WHERE l.num_client = r.num_client and
       r.num_immatriculation = l.num_immatriculation`

Answer (score 6):

You actually need a union:

```
SELECT English, French FROM T1
UNION
SELECT English, French FROM T2
```

If you don't care about duplicates, you can use UNION ALL

Edit after OP's comment:

```
SELECT l.num_client, l.id_agence, l.num_immatricul
FROM  locations l
UNION
SELECT r.num_client, r.id_agence, r.num_immatriculation
FROM  restitutions r
```

Comment: I have an error `query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Comment: @mkab, Remove l.num_client from the second part of query. I'm surprised you don't need to join locations and resitutions somehow?

Comment: @mkab your SQL shows you are trying to union 4 columns in the top statement with 5 columns in the bottom statement. `query block has incorrect number of result columns` means your two statements cannot be unioned together because they each contain a different number of result columns. Try removing `l.num_client` from the bottom statement or adding it to the top statement.

Comment: @mkab If you remove num_client, you'll get each record duplicated, my guess is that locations and restitutions have to be joined, do they share a key?

Comment: @wweicker, That's what I thought at first but he will end up with nothing but duplicates as the tables are the same

Comment: @vc74 Oh yeah, I see it now, no where clauses and the same tables in both statements ^_^

Comment: @mkab Then try the SQL I added, I used locations1 and restitutions1 (&2) as using the same tables twice would make very little sense so I guess you have different tables like in your initial example.

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try. And do you mean `locations1 l` or `locations l1` because table `locations1` won't exist?

Comment: @mkab In your initial example, you had 2 tables with matching columns (English and French), in the locations example, it looks like the tables don't have the same structure. In short, what are your English and French corresponding columns in locations and restitutions?

Comment: @vc: Ok i'm going to put the whole table for locations and restitutions in my original question.

Comment: @vc74: I've added both tables to the question

Comment: @mkab I've updated my query according to your tables definition, if I understand you correctly, you're trying to get the values from both tables using the columns they have in common.

Comment: yes that's what I want to do. I tried your query but it gives me 21 values from the two tables that contain 17 values for one and 15 values for the other. It kinda created some unwanted duplicates

Comment: @mkab Union will return a single row if all 3 fields are equal in both tables. Union All will run faster but create duplicates. Maybe you don't need the client number in which case you can remove the first field from both queries.

Comment: Actually in table location the last two values aren't "restituted" in the table locations. So I want these two values to be shown in the resulting table but with the column `km_restitution` and `km_parcouru` containing nothing

Comment: @vc74: removing client number reduces the value to 20 but I should have maximum of 15 values

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it.

```
SELECT tab1.English, tab1.French
 UNION
SELECT tab2.English, tab2.French
```

Comment: I have an error: `query block has incorrect number of result columns`

Answer (score 0):

For other readers who might have the same problem. From the experience I had with this problem, it would be a good idea to join tables locations and restitutions since both of them have almost the same attributes and data. I finally decided in changing my database and creating a new table that contains both the attributes of location and restitution and setting some not availabe values to `NULL`. This would reduce a lot of `joins` between tables and queries would be easier to handle.